# Cannot find a defined variable

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm really new to Dynamix AX 2009.

I was browsing the demo image from Microsoft to better understand how the application works. I checked a random method called `updateRFIDTagging()` in the form SalesQuotationTable

Now this last block of code really confuse me:

```
salesQuotationLine_ds.object(fieldnum(SalesQuotationLine, ItemTagging)).skip          (!itemTagging);
salesQuotationLine_ds.object(fieldnum(SalesQuotationLine, CaseTagging)).allowEdit     ( caseTagging);
salesQuotationLine_ds.object(fieldnum(SalesQuotationLine, CaseTagging)).skip          (!caseTagging);
salesQuotationLine_ds.object(fieldnum(SalesQuotationLine, PalletTagging)).allowEdit   ( palletTagging);
salesQuotationLine_ds.object(fieldnum(SalesQuotationLine, PalletTagging)).skip
```

I cannot find where the "salesQuotationLine_ds" is declared (and the code compile fine!). So my questions are:

1. Where is it declared?
2. Is there a shortcut/menu item that I can use to go to the declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `x_ds` is automatically defined for each `x` data source. There is a another auto declared variable `x_q` which is the data source query.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa629025.aspx (in the Remarks section).

For an easy (but not bullet proof) way to go to the declaration of a variable:

http://www.axaptapedia.com/AxGoToDeclaration

Answer (score 2):

_ds is a way to access the Form data source.